# SugarORM define ID when object created

Tags: android, sugarorm

I have a really simple object like this:

```
public class Item extends SugarRecord {
    Long id;
    String uuid;
    Integer minor;
    Integer major;
    public Item() { }
    public Item(Long id, String uuid, Integer minor, Integer major) {
        this.id = id;
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.minor = minor;
        this.major = major;
    }
}
```

I want the given ID to be a primary Key, I don't want the new ID to be automatically generated by sugarORM. Is it possible to do something like this? ... Sounds simple but I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. The syntax is correct. Problem was somewhere else. Database hasn't regenerated once I've updated the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use @Unique annotation.
Unique constraint can be specified using @Unique annotation. The default behaviour currently is to replace on conflict. So, if the unique constraint is violated, it'd replace the existing row.